# Triggering Wordress cron jobs function on server side

Tags: wordpress, cron

Suppose I have a Wordpresss cron job scheduler function ( which runs only on page loads ) on server as follows :

```
add_action('init','create_single_schedule');
add_action('single_cron_job','single_cron_function');
function single_cron_function(){
Do cron here
}
function create_single_schedule(){
        //check if event scheduled before
        if(!wp_next_scheduled('single_cron_job'))
         //schedule event to run after 60 seconds (or one minute)
         wp_schedule_single_event (time()+60, 'single_cron_job');
}
```

Now the problem is if no one opens my website , how can i call **create_single_schedule()**  to schedule/trigger a cron job ?

Comment: wp_cron is designed to run only when any user visits. You have to set up server cron manually in your cpanel, for that you need to take a look at this one https://www.pixelemu.com/documentation/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-server-cron-job

Comment: @VigneshPichamani its a plugin functionality which the installed host should do .Any other solution apart from yours  .Because in that case i have to manually set hosts where each plugin is installed

Comment: Apparently you have to specify how to setup server cron in your plugin documentation, so that any user want to setup server cron can do it. I think this is the only way you can achieve without any user. https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron

Answer (score 2):

You have to set up a real cron job on your server to call `wp-cron.php` at your desired interval.

First, disable WordPress cron on `wp-config.php`:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

If you have cPanel, set up a cron job to run every 5 minutes, or every hour and to execute the command:

```
wget http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php
```

More info:

- [Hooking WP-Cron Into the System Task Scheduler | Plugin Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/hooking-into-the-system-task-scheduler/)
- [Should I disable WP_CRON and instead trigger wp-cron.php from server every few mins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/253315/12615)
- [Insights into WP-Cron: An Introduction to Scheduling Tasks in WordPress](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/insights-into-wp-cron-an-introduction-to-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress--wp-23119)